# Escape Forward Slash in When Condition

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to do an Ansible "when compare string not equals"

like this :

```
when: "{{ result.stdout }} != '/var'"
```

How do I escape the / in '/var' because it's throwing a :

```
The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected '/'.
```

I have tried escaping the / with a \ but it throws the error :

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
The offending line appears to be:

shell: rsync -a /var/ "{{ result.stdout }}"
when: "{{ result.stdout }} != '\/var'"
                               ^ here
```

I have tried creating a variable in defaults :

defaults -> main.yml

```
var_partition: /var
```

tasks -> main.yml

```
when: "{{ result.stdout }} != {{ var_partition }}"
```

but it throws the error :

```
"The conditional check '{{ result.stdout }} != {{ var_partition }}' failed. 
The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected '/'. 
String: {% if /disk1 != /var %}
```

Comment: ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
The offending line appears to be:

  shell: rsync -a /var/ "{{ result.stdout }}"
  when: "{{ result.stdout }} != '\/var'"
                                 ^ here

Comment: The formatting isn't clear but the arrow is pointing to the \

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works :

```
when: "{{ result.stdout != '/var' }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced slashes with dashes and got rid of this error:

```
vars:
    - local_var_name: "{{ var_name | regex_replace('/', '-') }}"
tasks:
  some_task:
    ...
    when: local_var_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use braces in [`when` statement](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement):

> ... the when clause, which contains a raw Jinja2 expression **without double curly braces** ...

In your example, simply use:

```
when: result.stdout != '/var'
```